# How are these Covariant Derivative Identities found?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, gauge-theory, commutator, dirac-equation

In David Tong's [Gauge Theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) on page 137 near eq. (3.30) he makes use of the following expressions for the covariant derivative $D_{\mu}$

$$\frac{1}{2}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]D_{\mu}D_{\nu}=\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}][D_{\mu},D_{\nu}]\tag{1}$$

and

$$e^{-ikx}e^{D^2}e^{ikx}=e^{(D_{\mu}+ik_{\mu})^2}\tag{2}$$

I'm guessing the first is just a change of dummy indices in the second term of the commutator, but I don't see how the indices are dummy.

The second expression I'm more confused about. It looks like $x^{\mu}$ is acting like a generator of translation in momentum space, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Repeated indices are summed over so they are always dummy indices.

Comment: For the first write $D_\mu D_\nu=\frac12([D_\mu,\,D_\nu]+\{D_\mu,\,D_\nu\})$. Only the antisymmetric part survives contraction with $[\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu]$, which is antisymmetric. For the second use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_application_of_the_identity) so $e^{ikx}e^{D^2}e^{ikX}=e^{D^2}+[e^{D^2},\,ikx]$.

Comment: @J.G. Why is $[ikx,e^{D^{2}}]$ central?

Comment: @J.G. also I don't see how $[e^{D^2},ikx]$ gives $e^{(D_{\mu}+ik_{\mu})^2}$

Comment: Ah, I hadn't spotted the centrality requirement.

Comment: @MouazChikhani I think the second expression should be proven with gauge invariance: it effectively says $Ue^{D^2}=e^{D^{\prime2}}U,\,U:=e^{-ikx}$, with $D^\prime$ the gauge covariant derivative after applying a unitary transformation $U$. (It suffices to show $D^\prime=U DU^\dagger$.) You didn't say for which gauge theory Tong claims this result, but it looks like it's likely to be the Abelian case $\mathsf{U}(1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint for eq. (2):

$$e^{-ik\cdot x} f(D) e^{ik\cdot x}~=~f\left(e^{-ik\cdot x} D e^{ik\cdot x}\right)$$

and

$$\begin{align} e^{-ik\cdot x} D_{\mu} e^{ik\cdot x}~\stackrel{\text{Hadamard}}{=}&~e^{-ik_{\nu} [x^{\nu},\cdot]} D_{\mu}\cr 
~=~~~&D_{\mu}+ik_{\nu} [D_{\mu},x^{\nu}]\cr 
~=~~~&D_{\mu}+ik_{\mu},\end{align}$$
where we used [Hadamard's formula](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hadamard%27s+formula).

Comment: Does the second line follow from some form of BCH formula where we evaluate $[D_{\mu},ikx]$? I'm not entirely sure what the expression in the middle means and how we get it.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

By Leibnitz' rule
$$
e^{-ikx} \partial_x \{e^{ikx} f(x)\} = e^{-ikx}\{f(x)(\partial_x e^{ikx})+ e^{ikx}(\partial_x f)\}\\
= e^{-ikx}\{ f(x) (ik e^{ikx})+ e^{ikx}(\partial_x f)\}\\
= ik f(x) + \partial_x f(x)
=(\partial_x +ik)f(x).
$$
As $f(x)$ can be anything, we have
$$
e^{-ikx}\partial_x e^{ikx}= \partial_x+ik.
$$